# PHP mail attachment is not working

Tags: php, email

i am using php mail function to sent attachment, but its not working. Here is my code:

```
     $headers = array(
        "Mime-Version: 1.0",
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=charset=UTF-8",
        "From: Test <myemail>",
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project_name/test.txt" . "\"\r\n"; // For Attachment
    );    
    $headers = join("\r\n", $headers);

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Email sent successfully and file is attached, but the content is hidden.

Comment: I would like to recommend PhpMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for this task.

Comment: Read [PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail) link it may help you.

Comment: I dont want to use PHPMailer() . I want to knwo whats the problem in my code?

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/mixed; to use when you're sending attachment

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail/31428803#31428803

Comment: @SaadSuri, not working

Comment: where in you code do you put the content of the file into the mail to be sent? You only give a filename (or actually a complete path). That path is meaningfull on the server, but not on the tablet of the receiver. Only a filename like "contract.pdf" is meaningful

Comment: Are you getting any error or try `$success =mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message']; var_dump($errorMessage);
}`

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the body of an email in your mailbox, containing an attachment. Check for "boundries"  and for "hex encoded" parts, which are actually the attachment

Comment: Ivo P 's suggestions make good scene too.

Comment: @MahaDev if you solved it please post the solution.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu bro, none of the solution worked for me. I used sendgrid api for that :)

Comment: @MahaDev, thank you for your reply,  I will try on some server and let you know, with out any api or library .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use PHPMailer.

To use PHPMailer:

- Download the PHPMailer script from here: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient place in your project.
- Include the main script file -- require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');

Now use as :

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );
$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'nameOfFile.pdf' );
return $email->Send();
```

Comment: But i dont want to use PHPMailer() /. I want to know whats the problem in my code?

Comment: Please check this link if it helps. Thanks. http://www.tutdepot.com/php-e-mail-attachment-script/

Answer (score 0):

Your content type should be

```
"Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; charset=charset=UTF-8",
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313090/5321614), this can guide you solve your problem.

I also have a big doubt, if it is correct

```
 "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project_name/test.txt" . "\"\r\n"; // For Attachment
```

combination of single and double quote does not seems to good. Can you please change it to

```
 "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/project_name/test.txt" . "\"\r\n";
```

or try using single quote as you are not parsing any variable.

Comment: DO you think any settings with php.ini could cause this problem, are you able to send non attachment mails ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own code and don't want to implement the mail libraries. Please do it like this

```
$handle = fopen($file_name, "r");
$content = fread($handle, filesize($file_name));
fclose($handle);
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$boundary = md5("foobar");
$message = "I have some message";
//header

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

//plain text 
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

//attachment
$body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
$body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
$body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
$body .= $encoded_content;

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = "YOUR EMAIL ID";
$from = "Website <website@mydomain.com>";
$subject = "Test Attachment Email";

$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "document.pdf";

//$pdfdoc is PDF generated by FPDF
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}
```